# Meta tags are updating when serving, but are not updating when building

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, meta-tags, angular-universal

I have an Angular Universal where I need to update the meta tags dynamically, when serving it locally **(npm run dev:ssr)** and I view page source it is working as expected and the meta tags are updating. However, when I build and publish **(npm run build:ssr)** , the meta tags are not updating when viewing page source.

UPDATE:

After some testing turns out that if I am using an external dependency in the component, for some reason the meta tags no longer update.

component.ts:

```
import JSShare from "js-share"; --> This library is added as an external dependency in the angular.json file, and whenever included it is causing the above 

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any,
  ) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this.getProductById(id);
    });
}

  openSocialMedia($this, type: string){
    if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)){
        JSShare.go($this, {
          type: type,
        })
    }
  }

getProductById(id) {
    this.productService.getDetails(id).subscribe({
      next: result => {
        this.product = result;
        this.updateMetaTags();
      }
    });
  }

  updateMetaTags(){
    this.metaService.updateTag({property:'og:image', content: this.product.image}, "property='og:image'");
    this.metaService.updateTag({property:'og:title', content: this.product.name}, "property='og:title'");
    this.metaService.updateTag({property:'og:description', content: this.product.description}, "property='og:description'");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your component's **ngOnInit()** method, call **updateMetaTags()** after a short delay to ensure that the initial rendering is complete:

**Component.ts**

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private metaService: Meta) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
    const id = params['id'];
    this.getProductById(id);
  });
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.updateMetaTags();
  }, 1000); // Adjust the delay as needed
}

updateMetaTags() {
  this.metaService.updateTag({ property: 'og:image', content: this.product.image }, "property='og:image'");
  this.metaService.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: this.product.name }, "property='og:title'");
  this.metaService.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: this.product.description }, "property='og:description'");
}
```

By adding the delay and updating the meta tags on the client side, the tags will be modified after the initial server-side rendering and will reflect the dynamic data.

`**Updated Code**`

i created service file for set meta tags

**seo.service.ts**

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class SeoService {
  environment = environment
  constructor (private meta: Meta, private title:Title, public router:Router, @Inject(DOCUMENT) public dom) { }

  generateTags (config:ConfigType) {
    const keys = Object.keys(config);
    keys.forEach((key) => {
      if (config[key] === undefined || config[key] === 'undefined') {
        delete config[key];
      }
    });
    config = {
      title: 'title',
      description: 'description',
      keyword: null,
      image: null,
      slug: '',
      ...config
    };
    this.title.setTitle(config.title);
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'title', content: config.title });
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: config.description });
    if (config.keyword) {
      this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'keywords', content: config.keyword });
    }
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:url', content: (environment.SEO_WEB_URL + this.router.url) });
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:title', content: config.title });
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:description', content: config.description });
    // Cononical
    const canonical = this.dom.querySelector('link[rel=canonical]');
    canonical.href = (environment.SEO_WEB_URL + this.router.url);

    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:site_name', content: 'name' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content: environment.SEO_WEB_URL + this.router.url });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: config.title });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: config.description });
    if (config.image) {
      this.meta.addTag({ name: 'twitter:image', content: config.image });
      this.meta.addTag({ property: 'og:image', content: config.image });
    }
  }
}

interface ConfigType {
  title?: string,
  description?: string,
  image?: string,
  slug?: string,
  keyword?:string;
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { SeoService } from '../../../services/seo.service';

ngOnInit (): void {
    
    const title = 'title';
    const description = 'description';
    const keyword = '';
    this.seo.generateTags({ title, description, keyword });
  }
```

Comment: Adding a delay is counter productive, as it doesn't guarantee that the results have returned from the API.

Comment: @OsamaEl-Masri  i updated my answer can you please check it work for me both side server  and client.